# No match for operator '==' and '>' in Binary Tree template class - c++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, operator-keyword

I'm pretty new to binary search trees so please bear with me. I have a binary search tree class, that I first created only for integers. It was working correctly, so then I've had to convert it to a template class so it can handle objects. Now when trying to insert an object as a node, I get these errors. I understand that it means I may have to overload my '==' and '>' operators, but is that really necessary? And if so, what kind of logic would I need in my overload so that it can correctly compare the two types?

Would they need to be bool returns? I apologize, I'm only just learning aboust BST.

Insert node method:

```
template <class T>
void Bst<T>::insertNode(const T& insertItem)
{
    nodeType<T> *current;
    nodeType<T> *trailCurrent = nullptr;
    nodeType<T> *newNode;

    newNode = new nodeType<T>;
    newNode->info = insertItem;
    newNode->lLink = nullptr;
    newNode->rLink = nullptr;

    if(root == nullptr)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        current = root;
        while(current != nullptr)
        {
            trailCurrent = current;
            if(current->info == insertItem)
            {
                cout << "The item to be inserted is already ";
                cout << "in the tree -- duplicates are not "
                << "allowed." << endl;
                return;
            }
            else if(current->info > insertItem)
                current = current->lLink;
            else
                current = current->rLink;
        }
        if(trailCurrent->info > insertItem)
            trailCurrent->lLink = newNode;
        else
            trailCurrent->rLink = newNode;

    }
}
```

Error: `no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Date' and 'const Date')|` at

```
if(current->info == insertItem)
```

and error: `no match for 'operator>' (operand types are 'Date' and 'const Date')|` at

```
else if(current->info > insertItem)
```

This is where I call insertNode:

```
    ifstream infile("date.txt");
    Date dateObj;
    string date1;
    stringstream date;

    Bst<Date> dateTree;

    while(getline(infile, date1))
    {
        stringstream date1;
        string day;
        string month;
        string year;

        getline(date1,day,'/');
        getline(date1,month,'/');
        getline(date1,year);

        dateObj.SetDay(day);
        dateObj.SetMonth(month);
        dateObj.SetYear(year);
        dateTree.insertNode(dateObj);
        dateTree.inOrderTraversal();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `insertNode`?

Comment: Yes, I've included it in the question now

Comment: I think the diagnostics tell what is missing. Your comparisons use types that cannot be compared for equality or for which is greater than the other, since they are not trivially comparable (such as int,long, double, etc) so you need to define the missing comparison operators so the compiler can find them and apply them when you use `==` or `>` to compare them.

Comment: Presumably Date is a class you wrote. Did you define operator== and operator> for it?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes Date is a class I wrote, and no I haven't defined those operator overloads. However the error is showing up in my BST class. So are you saying i should be overloading the operator== and operator> in my Date class instead?

Comment: @thedafferg You can define them as free functions taking two `const Date &` parameters, or as members taking one parameter.

Comment: @thedafferg The error is naturally showing up at the place where these operators are used and not found. That is in the code of your `Bst` class in your case. And yes, you need to provide those comparators for your `Date` class (either as member or free functions). Or, you can pass a comparator to `Bst` by an additional template argument (Standard library containers works this way).

Comment: @DNT and Daniel Thank you, after creating the operator overloads in my Date Class the program now compiles.

Comment: Aside: `std::map<T>` only uses `<`, it does not use `==`, by testing both ways. That would look like `if (current->info < insertItem) ... else if (insertItem < current->info) ... else ...`

Comment: Aside 2: If you instead declare `nodeType<T> **current = &root;`, you don't need `trailCurrent`, or the `root == nullptr` test.